# How to allow access to an RPC endpoint of win32 process from UWP app

Tags: uwp

I have a win32 process which runs an RPC server. I want to allow my UWP app to access RPC endpoint of this win32 process. Can someone help how to do this?

I am trying something similar to custom capability approach as mentioned in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomCapability but without using any SCCD file.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for a specific app, or for any app? Is this something you're planning on side-loading, or putting in the Store?

Comment: I want to allow only specific UWP app to access my RPC endpoint. Basically I want to create UWP hybrid app using elevated desktop extension approach (https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/07/app-elevation-samples-part-3/ ) for win10 RS5 systems by leveraging existing custom capability win32 code (which uses RPC IO).

Comment: For the Store or for side loads? Is the Desktop component part of the same package or not?

Comment: It is for the store. Desktop component is part of the same package.

Comment: What have you tried? If it's part of the same package, RPC client in the UWP app "should work."